# XSL to replace value based on condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need some help with the following challenge I face in replacing the value of an element when 'some' other element has a specific value.

In my case I want to change the value of VKORG when the value of E1EDL21\LFART = 'LO'. In that case I want to take the value of E1ADRM1\PARTNER_ID where E1ADRM1\PARTNER_Q = 'WE'.

I didn't get any further than:

**Input xml:**

```
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
            <TKNUM>0000287306</TKNUM>
            <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                <VBELN>0081018890</VBELN>
                <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LFART>LO</LFART>
                </E1EDL21>
                <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
                    <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
                </E1ADRM1>
                <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                    <PARTNER_ID>12417</PARTNER_ID>
                </E1ADRM1>
            </E1EDL20>
            <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                <VBELN>0081018891</VBELN>
                <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LFART>LR</LFART>
                </E1EDL21>
                <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
                    <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
                </E1ADRM1>
                <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                    <PARTNER_ID>1112</PARTNER_ID>
                </E1ADRM1>
            </E1EDL20>
            <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                <VBELN>0081018892</VBELN>
                <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
                <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
                    <LFART>LO</LFART>
                </E1EDL21>
                <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
                    <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
                </E1ADRM1>
                <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
                    <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
                    <PARTNER_ID>12418</PARTNER_ID>
                </E1ADRM1>
            </E1EDL20>
        </E1EDT20>
    </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

**Current XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
      <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        
    <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>

        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDL20">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="E1EDL21/LFART='LO'">
                  <xsl:variable name="customer" select="E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='WE']/PARTNER_ID"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$customer"/>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current result:**

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287306</TKNUM>
      </E1EDT20>12417<E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <VBELN>0081018890</VBELN>
         <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
            <LFART>LO</LFART>
         </E1EDL21>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>12417</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
      </E1EDL20>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <VBELN>0081018891</VBELN>
         <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
            <LFART>LR</LFART>
         </E1EDL21>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>1112</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
      </E1EDL20>12418<E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <VBELN>0081018892</VBELN>
         <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
            <LFART>LO</LFART>
         </E1EDL21>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>12418</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
      </E1EDL20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

**Required result:**

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287306</TKNUM>
      </E1EDT20>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <VBELN>0081018890</VBELN>
         <VKORG>12417</VKORG>
         <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
            <LFART>LO</LFART>
         </E1EDL21>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>12417</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
      </E1EDL20>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <VBELN>0081018891</VBELN>
         <VKORG>0200</VKORG>
         <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
            <LFART>LR</LFART>
         </E1EDL21>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>1112</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
      </E1EDL20>12418<E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
         <VBELN>0081018892</VBELN>
         <VKORG>12418</VKORG>
         <E1EDL21 SEGMENT="1">
            <LFART>LO</LFART>
         </E1EDL21>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>5041</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
         <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
            <PARTNER_ID>12418</PARTNER_ID>
         </E1ADRM1>
      </E1EDL20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Hope I didn't make any typos. Link to my 'project' https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qC98Ut

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change the value of VKORG when the value of E1EDL21\LFART = 'LO'. In that case I want to take the value of E1ADRM1\PARTNER_ID where E1ADRM1\PARTNER_Q = 'WE'.

I believe that translates to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VKORG[../E1EDL21/LFART='LO']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='WE']/PARTNER_ID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect! I.O.U. Michael, thank you very much!